# Retrieve the Action or Func parameters after creating a Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

```
Task<string> t = wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
//create other tasks
//...
//...
//at this point I would like to know the url that was supplied for a task
```

I did not find any API in Task that will return me the Action or Func parameters that was used to create the task.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, there's no way to do that. It returns a Task, there's not meta-information there about the function that created it.

**EDIT:** Since it doesn't store this information, you just need to do it yourself, which is trivial.

```
var myTaks = new Dictionar<string, Task>();
myTasks.Add(url, wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
//Do the same for some other urls.
var thatOneTaskImLookingFor = wc[url];
```

Comment: Moreover.. Promise tasks don't have a delegate to begin with.